# meaning of infinitives

Tags: infinitives

> thankful (to do something) I was thankful **to** see they'd all arrived
>   safely.
>  thankful (for something) He wasn't badly hurt—that's
>   something **to** be thankful for.
>  ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/thankful))

I suppose that the first infinitive is the complement of *thankful*. *See* is preceding or the same time as the main clause.

The second infinitive is the post-modifier, *Be thankful for* is following or at the same time as the previous clause.

Does the syntactic difference make the semantic difference of infinitives?
(By any chance does the second infinitive contain the meaning of what one should do?)

Comment: There is no "semantic difference" here. The first example could just as easily be expressed as *I was thankful **that** they'd all arrived safely*, and the second as *that's something **I was** thankful for*.

Comment: An infinitive is called that because it is "unlimited" with respect to tense. It has no tense; its temporal reference is inferred from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any difference, since the meaning of *thankful* is "pleased about something good that has happened, or something bad that has not happened" in both the cases.
What changes is that in "thankful (to do something)" what follows *thankful* still has the same subject.

> Michael was thankful to arrive home safe. *Michael arrived home safe, and he was thankful for that.*

What follows *thankful* in "thankful (for something)" is something for which be thankful.

> She was thankful for the darkness which allowed her to slip away unnoticed. *The darkness allowed her to slip away unnoticed, and she was thankful for that.*

> She is thankful for being married to the richest man of the state. *She is married to the richest man of the state, and she is thankful for that.*

Comment: I know, I keep writing English when I am thinking of the Italian sentence. `:)` Funny enough, for Italian is exactly the opposite: It is _sposato con mia moglie_ (literally "married with my wife," but its meaning is "married to my wife"), where _con_ means _with_, and _sposato al partito_ ("to share the ideas the party has"), where _al_ means _to_.